# Can I use Eclipse "Mars" with the IBM MobileFirst Platform?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'd like to install **IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1** on **Eclipse Mars**.
Then, I saw follow page. But I don't see "Mars" word.
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/install/#studio. Can I use them together?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Mars is not officially supported for IBM MobileFirst Platform. However from UNofficial tests, everything seems to be OK.

Use it on your own risk, or stick with Eclipse Kepler/Luna.